Orphaned branches after rebase not being garbage collected
Recently a few times after rebasing I've seen what I assume are temporary commits and branches that get creating during the rebase.  Presumably these should get garbage collected, but they haven't been.

I've tried searching for various things related to 'git garbage collection' and 'git orphaned branches/commits' but I can't find anything similar to this issue.
I have run git gc --aggressive and git fsck --full both of which complete fine, but don't help.
I don't understand how these branches can continue to exist? My understanding is that any commit which isn't pointed to by either a commit or a ref would get garbage collected, so why aren't these.
It's a bit annoying to ignore these because they make it harder to read the graph.
If you can't advise on the direct issue, any clues on what to Google for would be helpful.

It seems that the issue was related to those branches/commits still existing in the reflog.
I rebase all the time and have done for years, so I have no idea why the issue occurred now.
I managed to fix it with:
git reflog expire --all --expire-unreachable=0

Which expires old reflog entries - in this case process all entries and expire unreachable commits older than 0 days.
This leads me to believe that if I'd waited until 30 days after the commits, then they would have been expired from the reflog and garbage collected at that point.
